# ConTeXt: How do I do calculations with /nextpage?

Tags: context, calculations, layout

This works great `\definelayout[\nextpage][new]` to set the layout for the next page.

How can I set the layout for the \nextpage+2 ? This didn't work `\definelayout[\nextpage+2][new]`

I tried a \numexpr but that didn't seem to work either.

```
\showframe
\setupexternalfigures[location=default] % get the cow
\setuppapersize[A4][A3,landscape] \setuparranging[2SIDE]
% works
\setuplayout[backspace=80mm, width=100mm, topspace=50mm, header=0mm, footer=0mm, height=200mm, margindistance=10mm, leftmargin=40mm]

\definelayout[new][backspace=80mm, width=100mm, topspace=50mm, header=0mm, footer=0mm, height=80mm, margindistance=10mm, leftmargin=40mm]
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
\starttext 

\definelayout[\nextpage][new]
\definelayout[\nextpage+2][new]
\dorecurse{10}{\input{knuth} }  
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\nextpage` only gives you the value of the next page. I don't know another way than doing some calculations. Something like this seems to work.

```
\showframe
\setupexternalfigures[location=default]
\setuppapersize[A4][A3,landscape] \setuparranging[2SIDE]
\setuplayout[backspace=80mm, width=100mm, topspace=50mm, header=0mm, footer=0mm, height=200mm, margindistance=10mm, leftmargin=40mm]
\definelayout[new][backspace=80mm, width=100mm, topspace=50mm, header=0mm, footer=0mm, height=80mm, margindistance=10mm, leftmargin=40mm]

\definecounter[Stanley]

\starttext 
\dorecurse{4}{{\darkblue \samplefile{knuth}}\par}
\setnumber[Stanley][\numexpr\realpagenumber+4\relax]
\definelayout[{\rawcountervalue[Stanley]}][new]
\dorecurse{20}{\samplefile{knuth}\par}  
\stoptext
```

[image: layout change four pages after the current one]

We have added the setup where the black turns blue, and it is in action four pages later.

Another option is to use `\definelayout` in the beginning of your document, when you are more or less done with everything. Then you can do `\definelayout[15][new]` to change the layout on page 15.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: I discussed this with Hans, and I think there will soon be a + option for the `\definelayout`, so that one can do `\definelayout[+4]` for this purpose. (It works on my machine.)

Comment: Nice. That will solve my problem.